# What file format should a simulation output its data in for easy animation with Blender?

Tags: animation, file-format

A physics simulation (academic) outputs at every timepoint of interest an `<unknown format>` file containing 3D info. An animation must be created by stringing these `<unknown format>` files together in Blender.

What should `<unknown format>` be? STL seems to be a straightforward choice, but [one must write a Python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15698/animate-stl-files-in-blender) in order to animate a sequence of STL files in Blender. Is there a file format that would be better suited to my task + Blender?

Comment: Use this great add-on for importing STL/PLY/OBJ sequences: https://github.com/neverhood311/Stop-motion-OBJ

Comment: @SergeL Thanks, that seems like a good solution.